# Solving "Real Life" Problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Michelle earns 5 dollars an hour when she works up to 10 hours a day. Michelle earns 12 dollars an hour for each hour over 10 hours a day she works. If she earned 92 dollars on Tuesday, how many hours did she work that day?

Comment: Michelle also doesn't show attempts at questions.

Answer (score 6):

Suggest method

- How much money, $M$, would Michelle earn if she works $10$ hours a day at $5$ an hour?
- Is $92$ more or less than this amount of money $M$?
- If $92$  is less than or equal to $M$, then she is in the position of having worked $\le 10$ hours at $5$ per hour and you can do a division by $5$ to work out the number of hours.
- If $92$  is more than $M$, then she is in the position of having worked $> 10$ hours with the extra hours at $12$ per hour. In this case you need to subtract $M$ from 92 and you can divide the resulting number by $12$ to figure out how many hours more than $10$ hours she worked.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently she did work overtime. Go ahead step by step:

- So, knowing how much she earned per normal hour, how much did she earn in the first 10 hours?
- How much did she earn in the overtime hours?
- Therefore, knowing the salary per overtime hour, how many overtime hours did she work?
- So that's how many hours in total?